# Incrementing session attribute on button click in thymeleaf and call url

Tags: spring-boot, thymeleaf

i am using thymeleaf in spring boot and reading the session attributes like this on the index page

```
  <p th:text="${session.counter}" th:unless="${session == null}">[...]</p>
```

where the counter is coming from the below function

```
 @RequestMapping({"/"})
String index(HttpSessbelow request ion session) {
    session.setAttribute("counter", "0");
    return "index";
}
```

Whenever someone click on the button on page , we should be able to increase the counter and call a url in the application , how can we achieve this

```
 <button onclick="/activate}">...</button> 


@RequestMapping({"/"})
String activate(HttpSession session) {
    if(session.getAttribute(counter) == 1){

    activate();
    return "thanksPage" ; 
    }

}
```

Answer (score 0):

Here's how I would structure it.

```
@RequestMapping("/")
public String start(HttpSession session) {
    session.setAttribute("counter", 0);
    return "redirect:/current";
}

@RequestMapping("/current")
public String current() {
    int counter = (Integer) session.getAttribute("counter);

    if (counter == 1) {
        activate();
        return "thanksPage"; 
    } else {
        return "index";
    }
}

@RequestMapping("/increment")
public string increment(HttpSession session) {
    session.setAttribute("counter", ((Integer) session.getAttribute("counter)) + 1);
    return "redirect:/current";
}
```

And the button should go to `/increment`

```
<button onclick="/increment">...</button>
```